# How to bake low carb bread in a Zojirushi bread machine model #BBCC-x20

Tags: equipment, bread

In a Zojirushi bread machine model BBCC-x20, what cycle would I bake a low carb recipe on as it does not have a low carb setting?  Also, where would I find low carb recipes for low carb bread specifically for this machine?  I have already checked the Zoji site and there are no low carb recipes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to comments I found on the internet about diabetics discussing this same question using this same model, one person recommended this:

> I changed the crust selection to light and reduced the flour by a tablespoon and the problem was solved.

You don't really need a recipe specific for this exact model, here is a low carb bread recipe designed for bread machines, you can also try the above tip.

http://www.food.com/recipe/best-low-carb-bread-bread-machine-102631

Answer (score 1):

I have a Zojirushi BB-PDC20_1.

I use the [recipe](https://www.food.com/recipe/best-low-carb-bread-bread-machine-102631) mentioned in soggyspaetzle’s answer and make it for a 2 lb. capacity (doubling the ingredients) and use the *white bread* option, *medium crust*.  Turns out grand!